# If $f(z) = u(z)+iv(z)$ is analytic, are both of $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I think the title says it all, if $f(z) = u(z)+iv(z)$ is analytic, are both of $u(z)$ and $v(z)$ analytic?

I betting that this is not the case and that there are some obvious counterexamples, but I couldn't think of any. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are $u,v$ real or complex?

Comment: And real-analytic or complex-analytic?

Comment: $u$ and $v$ will be harmonic(satisfy laplace equation) if $f=(u+iv)$ is analytic

Comment: "but I couldn't think of any" Well, at least mention the ones you tried.

Comment: how do you know they are obvious if you don't know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
$$u(z) = 1+e^{-\frac1{z^2}} \\
v(z) = i e^{-\frac1{z^2}} \\
f(z) = u(z) + iv(z) = 1
$$
$u(z)$ and $v(z)$ each have an essential singularity at $z=0$ wile $f(z)$ is analytic (and finite!) everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for the special case of an entire function $f$, that is analytic on whole of $\mathbb{C}$:

Let $u$ and $v$ be the real and imaginary part of $f$. Then $u$ and $v$ are both real.

By Picard's little theorem an entire non-constant function takes all values of $\mathbb{C}$ except possibly one. Since That is clearly not the case for  real-valued functions, $u$ and $v$ cannot be entire.

Comment: Liouville's theorem is good enough to show this!

Comment: But bazookas still kill flies.

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann differential equations already suffice, or the open mapping theorem.

Comment: Indeed, CRE would probably be easiest and more general (arbitrary domain), but I simply *like* the fact that it follows from Picard... XD

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x+iy) = x+iy$ is analytic everywhere, but $u(x+iy) = x$ is nowhere complex-differentiable. Proof: Fix $z_0=x_0+iy_0.$ Then check that

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(z_0+h) - u(z_0)}{h}$$

is $1$ as $h\to 0$ through real values, while the limit is $0$ if $h\to 0$ through imaginary values. Therefore the complex derivative $u'(z_0)$ fails to exist.